# How do I make a function option (I don't know how to call it)

Tags: c#, function, methods, authentication, md5

I am making a DLL that people can use as a login system.
the function I made should be coded like this at the moment:

```
SecureLogin.register.makeUser("Username", "Password", 2);
```

Right now you have to use 0 = plaintext 1 = Idk yet 2 = MD5
But to make it easier I want to replace the number 2 with something like this :

```
SecureLogin.HashMethod.MD5
```

I want to make it look like this :

```
SecureLogin.register.makeUser("Username", "Password", SecureLogin.HashMethod.MD5);
```

How do I make a method or function for this??
if I am unclear please tell me and I will describe in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an enum:

```
public enum HashMethod
{
    Plaintext,
    Ldk,
    MD5,
}
```

and then have your method take this enum as parameter:

```
public void makeUser(string username, string password, HashMethod method)
{
    if (method == HashMethod.Plaintext)
    {
        ...
    }
    else if (method == HashMethod.Ldk)
    {
        ...
    }
    else if (method == HashMethod.MD5)
    {
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Unknown hash method");
    }
}
```

and then when calling the function you could pass the corresponding value of the enum type:

```
SecureLogin.register.makeUser("Username", "Password", SecureLogin.HashMethod.MD5);
```

Comment: We don't need `1,2` here.

Comment: @King King What do you mean we don't need `1,2` here??

Comment: @Nobleleader13245 that comment was against the answer before update. Normally by default any enum will start from `0` and increase by 1 for next elements.